# Complexity $O(n^3)$ vs $O((\log n)^4))$

Tags: asymptotics

I would like to prove that $O(n^3)$ is bigger than $O((\log n)^4)$.

I thought that I can divide both powers with 4 so it is $$O\left(n^{\frac{3}{4}}\right)$$ vs $$O(\log n)$$ but then I don't know how I can prove that $$O(n^k)$$ is bigger than $O(\log n)$ for $k > 0$.

Comment: Can you show that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^3}{(\ln n)^4} = \infty$$

Or alternatively the limit of the reciprocal is zero?

Comment: Is it possible to prove it without using lim, I'm told to prefer to prove without lim whenever it is possible, sorry for not adding it in the description above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put $n=e^s$. Then $n^k=e^{ks}$ and $\log(n)=s$.

We know that 
$$n^k=e^{ks}>2^{ks}=(1+1)^{ks}\geq 1+ks>ks=k\log(n),$$ 
where the $\geq$ is Bernoulli's inequality. Therefore $\frac{1}{k}n^k>\log(n)$ for $n$ large.

Hence $O(n^k)\supset O(\log(n))$.